# how to insert a UIButton in UITextView at any cursor position in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cursor, position, uitextview

in my application i have a `UITextView`. In that `UITextView` user enter text,when user click  **UIButton (already in Toolbar)**, it need to insert a `UIButton` at cursors current position. How can i get the cursor's X and Y co-ordianates. programmatically?

my code is below **UIButton (already in Toolbar)**

```
-(void)inserButton
{
    UIButton *myButton  =   [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    myButton.frame      =   CGRectMake(30, 5, 10, 10);
    UIImage *Chkimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchk.png"];
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:Chkimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [note addSubview:myButton];
}
```

here i need to replace the value

```
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(X, Y, 10, 10);
```

is it possible to get the X and Y values of cursor.?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `caretRectForPosition` method for finding point of your cursor maybe then you can step forward

```
CGPoint cursorPosition = [textview caretRectForPosition:textview.selectedTextRange.start].origin;
```